# SQL sub query not working with group by clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL Server 2012. Can anyone tell me where i am going wrong ?

```
 SELECT 
                avg ( tbl.FirstBillComplete ) 
            FROM 
                ( select  l.MONTH, a.OverallScore, (a.FirstBillComplete), ( a.EmailComplete)
                    from  tbl_T1 a join calls.dbo.c1_LP l on a.QID = l.QID
                        union
                    select  l.MONTH, a.OverallScore, (a.FirstBillComplete), ( a.EmailComplete)
                    from  tbl_2 a join calls.dbo.C3_LP l on a.QID = l.QID
                    union ALL
                    select l.MONTH, a.OverallScore,  (a.FirstBillComplete), ( a.EmailComplete) 
                    from  tbl_3 a join c2 l on a.QID = l.QID 
                ) As tbl  
            GROUP BY tbl.MONTH
```

The error I get is :

```
No column was specified for column 7 of 'tbl'.
No column was specified for column 8 of 'tbl'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a column name for column 7 and 8 of tbl: use

```
'' AS MyColumn7,
```

For example.